# How can I run an if statement in the answer of a JOptionPane?

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I'm trying to do a specific task from the answer of the two options. Here's some of the code, but I don't know what's going on here.

```
String[] sex = { boy, girl };

JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,"Hey " +output1 +". Are  you a boy or a girl?", "Question",
            JOptionPane.YES_OPTION, JOptionPane.NO_OPTION,
            null, sex, sex[0]);

if(sex == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
{
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take the result of the `showOptionDialog` method:

```
int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
    "Hey " + output1 + ". Are  you a boy or a girl?", 
    "Question",
    JOptionPane.YES_OPTION, 
    JOptionPane.NO_OPTION,
    null, 
    sex, 
    sex[0]
);
```

and decide if it is a boy / girl using it.

If can be `JOptionPane.YES_OPTION` (`0`) or `JOptionPane.NO_OPTION` (`1`):

```
if ( result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION ) {
    System.out.println("boy");
} else { // optional if ( result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION )
    System.out.println("girl");
}
```

You can't compare `sex` and `JOptionPane.YES_OPTION` because they have different types (the first one is `String[]`, the second one is `int`).